# Distinguish between numbers and alphabet in a string

Tags: c

I am trying to build a TCPIP communication between a server and a client in visual studio , the client will accept a string from the keyboard, and he will send the string to the server only if it is numbers not alphabet I tried the below code but it seems there is something wrong.

```
while (rc == SOCKET_ERROR);                         //try as long till there is connection (no Socket Error)

printf("conected with %s..\n\n", address);


do
{

    printf("Please insert the Blood pressure values for further Diagnostic\n ");
    gets(data);
    char i;
    for (i = data[0]; i <= MAX; i++)
    {

        char n = data[i];
        if ((strlen(data) > MAX) || (strlen(data) == 0)) 
        {

            printf("argument not allowed!\n\n");
            memset(data, '\0', strlen(data));
            continue;

        }
        if ((n >= 'a' && n <= 'z') ||( n >= 'A' && n <= 'Z'))

        {

            printf("you have to enter a number !\n\n");
            memset(data, '\0', strlen(data));                   
            continue;
            //next iteration

        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at isdigit() in ctype.h and dont use gets, instead use fgets

Comment: In case `rc`  was set to `SOCKET_ERROR` prior to this `while (rc == SOCKET_ERROR);` it will loop forever.

Comment: Sry, but to me this looks as if you either got confused or simply have no clue what you are doing here. Probably start over turning to your favourite C primer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `for (i = data[0]; i <= MAX; i++)`  I think you would want to initialise 'i' with 0 and not data[0] and want to traverse data with i as index. That's what is causing the issue
2. Why would you want to do this operation in a loop? It should be a one-time operation:

   ```
   if ((strlen(data) > MAX) || (strlen(data) == 0)) 
   {
       printf("argument not allowed!\n\n");
       memset(data, '\0', strlen(data));
       continue;
   }
   ```
3. The 'continue' in second if will again iterate over the for loop. You would want to 'break' from here to loop in do-while loop

Comment: I think I make a mistake by copying the code I will rectify it, however, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is wrong.Instead , try:

```
do{
     int i;
     int flag = 0;
     gets(data);
     if ((strlen(data) > MAX) || (strlen(data) == 0)) 
             {
                  printf("argument not allowed!\n\n");
                  memset(data, '\0', strlen(data));
                  continue;
             }
     for(i = 0 ; i<strlen(data) ; i++){
         if (!isdigit(data[i]))
         {
             printf("you have to enter a number !\n\n");
             memset(data, '\0', strlen(data));                  
             flag = 1;break;
         }
     }
     if(flag){
          continue;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 500

int main() {
    char data[100] = { 0 };

    do
    {
        printf("Please insert the Blood pressure values for further Diagnostic\n ");
        if (gets(data) != NULL && strlen(data) <= MAX) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {
                if (!isdigit(data[i])) {
                    printf("you have to enter a number !\n\n");
                }
                else {
                    // process value
                    putchar(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid argument\n\n");
        }
    } while (1 == 1);  // you would have to decide when to terminate
}
```